# OpenCV (Python): Construct Rectangle from thresholded image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

The image below shows an aerial photo of a house block (re-oriented with the longest side vertical), and the same image subjected to *Adaptive Thresholding* and *Difference of Gaussians*.

[Images: Base; Adaptive Thresholding; Difference of Gaussians](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJSs1.png)

The roof-print of the house is obvious (to the human eye) on the AdThresh image: it's a matter of connecting some obvious dots. In the sample image, finding the blue-bounded box below -

[Image with desired rectangle marked in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I31iu.png)

I've had a crack at implementing `HoughLinesP()` and `findContours()`, but get nothing sensible (probably because there's some nuance that I'm missing). The python script-chunk that fails to find anything remotely like the blue box, is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# read in full (RGBA) image - to get alpha layer to use as mask
img = cv2.imread('rotated_12.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
grey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur_base = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey,(9,9),0)
blur_diff = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey,(15,15),0)
_,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(grey,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grey,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)


DoG_01 = blur_base - blur_diff
edges_blur = cv2.Canny(blur_base,70,210)

# Find Contours
(ed, cnts,h) = cv2.findContours(grey, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:4]
for c in cnts:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.1*cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)
cv2.drawContours(grey, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

# Hough Lines
minLineLength = 30
maxLineGap = 5

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges_blur,1,np.pi/180,20,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
print "lines found:", len(lines)
for line in lines:
    cv2.line(grey,(line[0][0], line[0][1]),(line[0][2],line[0][3]),(255,0,0),2)

# plot all the images
images = [img, thresh, DoG_01]
titles = ['Base','AdThresh','DoG01']

for i in xrange(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(1,len(images),i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i]), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.savefig('a_edgedetect_12.png')

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to set things up without excessive parameterisation. I'm wary of 'tailoring' an algorithm for just this one image since this process will be run on hundreds of thousands of images (with roofs/rooves of different colours which may be less distinguishable from background). That said, I would love to see a solution that 'hit' the blue-box target - that way I could at the very least work out what I've done wrong.

If anyone has a quick-and-dirty way to do this sort of thing, it would be awesome to get a Python code snippet to work with.

The 'base' image ->

[Base Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMvRx.png)

Comment: What about canny edge?

Comment: Do good adaptive thresholding, open & close (or your own amount of dilation and erosion), apply canny edge detection, apply find countours, and  filter contours with atleast 4 corners.

Comment: I might be able to help you out, but I'm at work. And this might take about half an hour or so.. I'd try to get back after 10 hours.

Comment: have you tried working with a different color space?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the following:
1. Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization-[CLAHE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html#clahe-contrast-limited-adaptive-histogram-equalization) and convert to gray-scale.
2. Gaussian Blur & [Morphological transforms](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) (dialation, erosion, etc) as mentioned by @bad_keypoints. This will help you get rid of the background noise. This is the most tricky step as the results will depend on the order in which you apply (first Gaussian Blur and then Morphological transforms or vice versa) and the window sizes you choose for this purpose.
3. Apply Adaptive thresholding
4. Apply Canny's Edge detection
5. Find contour having four corner points

As said earlier you need to tweak with input parameters of these functions and also need to validate these parameters with other images. As it might be possible that it will work for this case but not for other cases. Based on trial and error you need to fix the parameter values.